# Prove that the identity map $(C[0,1],d_1) \rightarrow (C[0,1],d_\infty)$ is not continuous

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

$$d_\infty = \max|x_i - y_i|$$
$$d_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - y_i|$$

The first part of this question was to prove that the identity map $$(C[0,1],d_\infty) \rightarrow (C[0,1],d_1)$$ is continuous, which I did using $\epsilon = n \delta$. I'm not sure how to prove it is not continuous in the opposite direction. I tried using my logic in reverse but it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone offer any hints or suggestions?

Comment: What are $d_1$ and $d_\infty$?

Comment: Isabelle, we are not reading straight from your mind. We need more details

Comment: Are they not standard metrics? My lecturer talks as if $d_1$ and $d_\infty$ are universal the same way you'd define the Euclidean metric. Editing now

Comment: Hint: consider triangles of basis $1/n$ and height $1$, then let $n$ tend to infinity.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how do you calculate $d_1(f,g)$ when $f,g\in C[0,1]$? What's that even mean? Edit: Ah, Martin Argerami figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the identity map $C[0,1],d_1\to C[0,1],d_{\infty}$ bounded? $C[0,1],d_1$ is incomplete

$f_n(x)= 2nx; x\in [0,{1\over 2n}]$

$f_n(x)= 2-2nx; x\in [{1\over 2n},{1\over n}]$

$f_n(x)= 0$ else

$f_n$ converges to $0$ in $d_1$, it does not convrges  to $d_{\infty}$ norm,since the value of $\sup f_n(x)=1$ always

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that $d_1$ and $d_\infty$ are the distances induced by the one and infinity-norms, respectively, i.e. 
$$
d_1(f,g)=\|f-g\|_1=\int_0^1|f-g|,\ \ \ \ d_\infty(f,g)=\|f-g\|_\infty=\sup\{|f(t)-g(t)|:\ t\in[0,1]\}.
$$.

It is probably not efficient to think of this problem in terms of the definition of continuity. Rather, since the identity is a linear mapping, one wants to show that it is bounded in one direction and unbounded in the other one.

On the one hand, you have $d_1(f,g)\leq d_\infty(f,g)$, since
$$
\int_0^1|f|\leq \|f\|_\infty\,\int_0^11=\|f\|_\infty.
$$
To show that the identity is not continuous the other way, we need to find functions with constant $1$-norm, and arbitrarily large infinity-norm. For example, we could take
$$
f_n(t)=\begin{cases}n,&\mbox{ if }t\in[0,1/n),\\ n(2-nt),&\mbox{ if }t\in[1/n,2/n)\\0,&\mbox{ if }t\in[2/n,1]\end{cases}
$$
This $f_n$ is continuous, $\|f_n\|_\infty=n$, $\|f_n\|_1=3/2$.

Comment: There is a little linear black box in your argument, which is not needed if we simply construct $f_n$ such that $\|f_n\|_1\rightarrow 0$ and yet $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $0$. Maybe that would be more appropriate given the "metric" aspect of the question.

Comment: Could you possibly explain what the "linear" thing means, and how it relates? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: A map $F$ between vector spaces $V,W$ is linear if $F(x+y)=F(x)+F(y)$, $F(cx)=cF(x)$ for vectors $x,y$ in $V$ and a scalar $c$. In your question, $V=W=C[0,1]$. But the two vector spaces carry a norm (you can think that here the norm of a vector is its distance to $0$). As $V$ is infinite-dimensional, it turns out that not every linear map is continuous. A linear map between normed spaces is continuous if and only if it is *bounded*, which means there exists $k>0$ such that  $\|F(x)\|\leq k\|x\|$ for all $x\in V$. This is what Functional Analysis studies.