# Are $(C[0,1],d_\infty)$ and $(C[0,1],d_1)$ homeomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Two metric spaces are said to be homeomorphic if there is a bijection f between them such that $f$ and  $f^{-1}$ are both continuous.

Consider $C[0,1]$ with metrics:

$d_\infty (f,g)=\max_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$

$d_1(f,g)=\int_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|dx$

We already know that the identity map $(C[0,1],d_1)→(C[0,1],d_∞)$ is not continuous ([Prove that the identity map $(C[0,1],d_1) \rightarrow (C[0,1],d_\infty)$ is not continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545760/prove-that-the-identity-map-c0-1-d-1-rightarrow-c0-1-d-infty-is-not)). Does this imply $(C[0,1],d_∞)$ and $(C[0,1],d_1)$ are not homeomorphic?

Or could you find a bijection which is continuous in both direction?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes they are, as both are separable metric locally convex topological vector spaces. This is a classic theorem (but hard to prove in general). It might be easier in specific cases. E.g. the $\ell_p$ spaces have explicit homeomorphisms.

Comment: No, the identity map is continuous in that direction.

Comment: @zhw I'm sorry. I mistakenly typed the question and I have fixed the error.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Does that theorem really hold without knowing that the spaces are complete?

Comment: @EricWofsey you're right. We need completely metrisable instead of metrisable

Comment: @Henno Brandsma  Could you please give a reference on this theorem?

Comment: Dobrowolski and Toruńczyk (1979) proved that all infinite dimensional separable completely metrisable vector spaces that are absolute retracts are homeomorphic. And Dugundji showed that every locally convex vector space is an absolute retract.

Comment: On metric linear spaces homeomorphic to l2 and compact convex sets homeomorphic to Q in Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci. Sér. Sci. Math.

Comment: But the theorem does not apply here, as one of the two is not completely metrisable

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not. Confirming a conjecture of Banach, Victor Klee proved that if there is a complete metric on a normed (or, more generally, metrizable topological vector) space *inducing the norm (vector space) topology* then the norm (uniformity induced by the vector space topology) is complete. This can be seen, e.g., in Köthe's book *topological Vector Spaces I*, page 165.

Clearly, $d_1$ is not complete.

Comment: But we're talking about a homeomorphism, which doesn't have to preserve a uniformity.

Comment: Sorry, a part of the argument was missing. Of course, it is the surprising point in Klee's theorem that the complete metric may induce a very different uniformity.